# Make multi threaded 1 million inserts to MongoDb using Node JS scripts

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multithreading, worker-thread

I have a isolated sync server that pulls a tab limited text file from a external ftp server and updates(saves) to mongodb after processing.
My code looks like this

```
//this function pulls file from external ftp server 
async function upsteamFile() {
  try {
    let pythonProcess = spawn('python3', [configVar.ftpInbound, '/outbound/Items.txt', configVar.dataFiles.items], {encoding: 'utf8'});
    logger.info('FTP SERVER LOGS...' + '\n' + pythonProcess.stdout);
    await readItemFile();
    logger.info('The process of file is done');

    process.exit();
  } catch (upstreamError) {
    logger.error(upstreamError);

    process.exit();
  }
}


//this function connects to db and calls processing function for each row in the text file.
async function readItemFile(){
  try{
  logger.info('Reading Items File');

  let dataArray = fs.readFileSync(configVar.dataFiles.items, 'utf8').toString().split('\n');
  logger.info('No of Rows Read', dataArray.length);
  await dbConnect.connectToDB(configVar.db);
  logger.info('Connected to Database', configVar.db);
  while (dataArray.length) {
      await Promise.all( dataArray.splice(0, 5000).map(async (f) => {
      splitValues = f.split('|'); 
      await processItemsFile(splitValues)
    })
    )
    logger.info("Current batch finished processing")
  }
  logger.info("ALL batch finished processing")
}
  catch(PromiseError){
    logger.error(PromiseError)
  }
}




async function processItemsFile(splitValues) {
  try {
      // Processing of the file is done here and I am using 'save' in moongoose to write to db
     // data is cleaned and assigned to respective fields 
        if(!exists){
           let processedValues = new Products(assignedValues);
           let productDetails = await processedValues.save();  
    }
      return;
    }
  catch (error) {
   throw error
  }
}
upstream()
```

So this takes about 3 hours to process 100,000 thousand rows and update it in the database. 
Is there any way that I can speed this up. I am very much limited from the hardware. I am using a ec2 instance based linux server with 2 core and 4 gb ram.
Should I use worker threads like *microjob* to run multi-threads . if yes , then how would I go about doing it
Or is this the maximum performance?

Note : I cant do *bulk update* in mongodb as there is mongoose pre hooks are getting triggered on *save*

Answer (score 0):

You can always try a bulk update with the use of `updateOne` method.

I would consider also using the `readFileStream` instead of `readFileSync`.

With the event-driven architecture you could push, let's say every *100k* updates into array chunks and bulk update on them simultaneously.

You can trigger a pre `updateOne()` (instead of `save()`) hook during this operation.

I have solved a similar problem (updating 100k CSV rows) with the following solution:

1. Create a `readFileStream` (thanks to that, your application won't consume much heap memory in case of the huge files)

I'm using CSV-parser npm library to deconstruct a CSV file into separate rows of data:

```js
let updates = [];
fs.createReadStream('/filePath').pipe(csv())
    .on('data', row => {
        // ...do anything with the data
        updates.push({
            updateOne: {
                filter: { /* here put the query */ },
                update: [ /* any data you want to update */ ],
                upsert: true /* in my case I want to create record if it does not exist */
            }
        })
    })
    .on('end', async () => {
        await MyCollection.bulkWrite(data)
            .catch(err => {
                logger.error(err);
            })

        updates = []; // I just clean up the huge array
    })
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include [example]. See [answer].