# Nested promise.all code is running synchronous while asynchronous is expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I think I'm doing something wrong inside a nested `Promise.all` part of my NodeJs script. I have a directory with multiple .csv files. Each file must be read in so that a database record can be made from each row. If a row fails I add the row to an array of failed rows which I write to a new .csv file after all the files have been processed.

Reading the files is done asynchronously. For example. I see that file 3 is read before file 1 and then file 4 is read in followed by file 2 etc.

Once I am in the nested part where the rows have to be written to the database the script works synchronously and I get in my logs:

```
...
Done filtering row 3327 in file 1
Done filtering row 3328 in file 1
Done filtering row 3329 in file 1
Done filtering row 3330 in file 1
Done filtering row 3331 in file 1
...
```

While I expect this

```
...
Done filtering row 120 in file 1
Done filtering row 2 in file 3
Done filtering row 121 in file 1
Done filtering row 122 in file 1
Done filtering row 20 in file 2
Done filtering row 3 in file 3
Done filtering row 4 in file 3
...
```

My code looks like this (I removed some side-functions that are not that importend for this question)

```
const start = async () => {
    try {
        // Connect to database
        await connectDB(process.env.DATABASE_URL);

        // Get CSV files from data directory
        const file_list = await getCSVFilesFromFolder('data');
    
        await Promise.all(file_list.map(async (file_path, i) => {
            // Read file
            const file = await readFileFromPath(file_path);
            console.log(`Done reading file ${i}`);

            // Parse file
            const parsed_rows = await parseCSV(file);
            console.log(`Done parsing file ${i}`);

            // Loop and create company for each row
            return Promise.all(parsed_rows.map((row, j) => {
                new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
                    // THIS PART IS SYNCHRONOUS
                    try {
                        // Filter data
                        const filtered_data = filterData(row);
                        const vat_number = `BE${row.BTWNUMMER}`;
                        console.log(`Done filtering row ${j} in file ${i}`);

                        // Find company
                        const company = await Company.findOne({ vat_number });

                        // Create company if not exists
                        if(!company) {
                            await Company.create({ ...filtered_data }).catch(err => {
                                failed_company_creations.push({
                                    ...filtered_data,
                                    error: err?.message
                                })
                            })
                            console.log(`Created company for row ${j} in file ${i}`);
                        } else {
                            console.log(`Company found for row ${j} in file ${i}`);
                        }

                        resolve();
                    } catch(err) {
                        reject(err);
                    }
                });
            }));
        }));

        console.log('Done writing to database');
        
        // Write errors to file
        const failed_company_creations_csv = new ObjectsToCsv(failed_company_creations);
        await failed_company_creations_csv.toDisk('./failed_company_creations.csv');
        console.log('Failed company creations successfully saved to disk');

    } catch(error) {
        console.log(`Crashed`);
        console.log(error);
    }
};
  
start();
```

If I change all the file parts and database logic to a fake async/wait method it's working like expected

```
const stall = async (stallTime = 3000) => {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, stallTime));
}

const getRandomInt = (min, max) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

const start = async () => {
    try {
        // Get CSV files from data directory
        const arrays = Array(20).fill().map((v,i)=>i);
    
        await Promise.all(arrays.map(async (file_path, i) => {
            // Read file
            const file = await stall(getRandomInt(100, 3000));
            console.log(`Done reading file ${i}`);

            // Parse data
            const parsed_rows = await stall(getRandomInt(100, 3000));
            console.log(`Done parsing file ${i}`);

            const sub_arrays = Array(20).fill().map((v,i)=>i);

            // Loop and create company for each row
            return Promise.all(sub_arrays.map((row, j) => {
                new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
                    try {
                        // Filter data
                        const filtered_data = await stall(getRandomInt(100, 1000));
                        console.log(`Done filtering row ${j} in file ${i}`);

                        // Find company
                        const company = await stall(getRandomInt(50, 4000));

                        // Create company if not exists
                        await stall(getRandomInt(50, 2000));
                        console.log(`Created company for row ${j} in file ${i}`);

                        resolve();
                    } catch(err) {
                        reject(err);
                    }
                });
            }));
        }));

        console.log('Done writing to database');
        
        // Write errors to file
        console.log('Failed company creations successfully saved to disk');

    } catch(error) {
        console.log(`Crashed`);
        console.log(error);
    }
};
  
start();
```

Output

```
Done reading file 13
Done reading file 11
Done reading file 3
Done parsing file 13
Done reading file 16
Done reading file 4
Done filtering row 19 in file 13
Done reading file 2
Done filtering row 11 in file 13
Done filtering row 8 in file 13
Done parsing file 2
Done reading file 15
Done filtering row 1 in file 13
Done filtering row 4 in file 13
Done filtering row 15 in file 13
Done reading file 17
Done reading file 0
Done filtering row 3 in file 13
Done filtering row 14 in file 13
Done reading file 18
Done filtering row 17 in file 13
Done filtering row 18 in file 2
Done filtering row 3 in file 2
Done filtering row 10 in file 13
Done filtering row 15 in file 2
Done filtering row 7 in file 13
Done filtering row 5 in file 2
Done filtering row 10 in file 2
Done filtering row 11 in file 2
```

Comment: `new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {` doesn't make sense

Comment: "*`THIS PART IS SYNCHRONOUS`*" - well yes, it is! The ``const filtered_data = filterData(row); const vat_number = `BE${row.BTWNUMMER}`;`` statements that lead up to the ``console.log(`Done filtering row ${j} in file ${i}`);`` **are synchronous**, what's unexpected about that leading to synchronous execution?

Comment: @Bergi I expect that piece to be synchronous while `await Promise.all(file_list.map(async (file_path, i) => {` is running asynchronous such that the code processes multiple blocks of code from the first iteration simultaneously.

`Done parsing file 2 | Done reading file 15 | Done filtering row 1 in file 13 | Done filtering row 4 in file 13 | Done filtering row 15 in file 13` instead of `Done filtering row 3327 in file 1 | Done filtering row 3328 in file 1 | Done filtering row 3329 in file 1`

Comment: No JavaScript code (in the same realm) is processed "simultaneously". `file_list.map(…)` is still a normal loop calling functions, one call for each array element, one after the other. The asynchrony (which is what allows JS to return from the function call and continue with the loop) kicks in only with the `Company.findOne(…)` and `stall(…)` calls that you `await`, deferring the code after the `await` (and only that!) until when the promise is settled.

Comment: Ok, then what can I do to make this code faster? There are 56 files to be read in with an average of 32.000 lines so almost 1.8 million rows that has to be processed. If a .map() is calling each element one by one it will take way too long to process.

Comment: The `map` does not matter at all. Even a loop over an array of a million items will be done in a short time. Your problem is making 1.8 million `Company.findOne()` calls to the database.

Comment: Your "too long to process" is likely referring to all the IO operations that need to happen, not the in-memory processing, meaning you are io bound, not cpu bound. You need to minimize how often you read or write data to a disk or database. Maybe this can serve as inspiration : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61618217/make-multi-threaded-1-million-inserts-to-mongodb-using-node-js-scripts

Comment: @Bergi What do you suggest as a solution to that? I skipped a part of the code to ask this question. I'm doing way more calls to the database. First I check for a company. If the company does not exist I skip the rest of the code. Otherwise I complete the object with additional data out of the .csv file without overriding existing data. Afterwards I do a `Company.findOneAndUpdate()` to update the company together with an extra source property. After this is done I'm doing some operations for Contacts. If a contact exists I'm updating the object otherwise I'm creating the contact. 1/2

Comment: I have run the script without the database actions and it would update 900.000 companies, create 1.4 million contacts and update 1475 contacts. 2/2

Comment: @M.Gallant I'll check this option but I'm not sure if it's possible in my case. I can only add data if it does not exists or is null. I don't want to override data

Comment: @Thore Surely mongodb has methods that allow bulk update and creation of documents?

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes about the possibilities within MongoDB there is no way to execute an updateOrCreate in a single operation and is there no way to search a document and complete it with an object with more/less parameters than the original one while the original data can't be overwritten unless it's undefined/null/"". Will check in the documentation what I can find

Comment: @Thore while it would be optimal, you don't need to aim for a single operation. Minimizing them is the goal. For instance, "find-ing" all the companies (or a batch quantity of companies like 1k-10k at a time) then doing the required updateMany and insertMany. Those 3 bulk operations per 1k-10k elements have far less overhead than 2 operations per element (or even a single operation per element for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that you need to return the promise from your map function, or do not use braces.  Your promise.all is receiving an array of undefined values the way it is now.

```
            // Loop and create company for each row
            return Promise.all(sub_arrays.map((row, j) => {
               return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
```

or

```
            // Loop and create company for each row
            return Promise.all(sub_arrays.map((row, j) =>
                new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
```

Comment: Really it should be neither of those. Just `Promise.all(sub_arrays.map(async (row, j) => {` - no `new Promise` anywhere